# Play can't find database

Tags: scala, jdbc, playframework

So, for 3 days now I have had various problems with Play, I am new to the framework, but I don't get what is happening. So, after I was unable to use Slick, due to some futures never returning a value, I decided to switch to Anorm. It worked, until I decided to add a second repository... after which, I am now unable to load my page because I keep getting this:

```
@769g71c3d - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find database for pmf
  at dao.ActivityTypeRepository.<init>(ActivityTypeDAO.scala:13)
  at dao.ActivityTypeRepository.class(ActivityTypeDAO.scala:13)
  while locating dao.ActivityTypeRepository
    for the 1st parameter of services.ActivityTypeServiceImpl.<init>(ActivityTypeService.scala:17)
  while locating services.ActivityTypeServiceImpl
  while locating services.ActivityTypeService
```

The database is input correctly, I can connect to it via terminal and via datagrip... Has anyone ever had a similar issue?

As requested, here is my configuration:

```
slick.dbs.default.profile = "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pmf"
```

These are my classes:

```
@Singleton

class ActivityTypeRepository @Inject()(dbapi: DBApi)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {

    private val db = dbapi.database(RepositorySettings.dbName)

    private[dao] val activityTypeMapping = {

        get[Int]("activityType.id") ~
        get[String]("activityType.name") map {
            case id ~ name => ActivityType(id, name)
        }
    }

    def listAll: Future[Seq[ActivityType]] = Future {

        db.withConnection { implicit conn =>

            SQL("SELECT * FROM ActivityType").as(activityTypeMapping *)
        }
    }
}

@Singleton
class UserRepository @Inject()(dbApi: DBApi)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext){

    private val db = dbApi.database(RepositorySettings.dbName)

    private[dao] val userMapping = {

        get[Option[Long]]("users.id") ~
          get[String]("users.email") ~
          get[Option[String]]("users.name") ~
          get[Option[String]]("users.surname") map {
            case id ~ email ~ name ~ surname => User(id, email, name, surname)
        }
    }

    def add(user: User): Future[Option[Long]] = Future {

        db.withConnection { implicit conn =>

            SQL"INSERT INTO users(id, email, name, surname) VALUES (${user.id}, ${user.email}, ${user.name}, ${user.surname})".executeInsert()
        }
    }

    def find(id: Long): Future[Option[User]] = Future {

        db.withConnection { implicit conn =>

            SQL"SELECT * FROM User WHERE id = $id".as(userMapping *).headOption
        }
    }

    def findByEmail(email: String): Future[Option[User]] = Future {

        db.withConnection { implicit conn =>

            SQL"SELECT * FROM User WHERE email = $email".as(userMapping *).headOption
        }
    }

    def listAll: Future[Seq[User]] = Future {

        db.withConnection { implicit conn =>

            SQL("SELECT * FROM User").as(userMapping *)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Added to application.conf

```
db {
   default.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
   default.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pmf_visualizations"
}
```

but no change.

Comment: Marin, you probably should show us more details of your configuration

Comment: What is your database name? you seems forgot to set that in the config file, it is now `DATABASENAME` you need to replace it with your real database name

Comment: I did replace it.

Comment: DB conf for Slick plugin (pasted) is not the one for Play JDBC